# What are the restrictions on the azimuthal quantum number $\ell$ for $\sigma$ transitions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, molecules

I know that $\pi$ transitions only allow $\Delta \ell = 1$, but what about $\sigma$ transitions? How are they restricted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\pi$, $\sigma$ - atomic transitions with respect to the magnetic field axis](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213736/)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That question doesn't addresses the azimuthal quantum number

Comment: I believe it's $\Delta l= 0, \pm 2$, but I'm not absolutely sure about that, also I don't have an argument to explain why. I think that to be sure, we'd have to check the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients. I'm interested in the answer too